# Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' while connecting mongodb through Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

I am trying to connect mongoDb with Spring's mongoTemplate. I also tried changing version of 'spring-data-mongodb' from 1.7.2.RELEASE to 1.8.2.RELEASE, but even that didn't work.

Below is my code as used in the project.

Here's my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.storeApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>storeApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Store Application</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>storeApp</finalName>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

My SpringMongoConfig file

```
    package com.storeApp.config;

    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory;

    import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

    @Configuration
    public class SpringMongoConfig1 {

        public @Bean
        MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception{
            return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(), "storeApp");
        }

        public @Bean
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception{
            MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
            return mongoTemplate;
        }

    //  ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringMongoConfig.class);
    //  MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations)ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");
    }
```

This is my main class

```
    package com.storeApp.core;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;

import com.storeApp.config.SpringMongoConfig1;
import com.storeApp.config.SpringMongoConfig2;
import com.storeApp.model.Store;

public class StoreMainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringMongoConfig1.class);
        MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations)ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");

        Store store = new Store("Sample store 1", "Street 1", "City 1", (float) 35.4);
        System.out.println("into main method");
//      mongoOperation.save(store);
    }
}
```

Stacktrace :

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Oct 18, 2016 10:08:47 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
Oct 18, 2016 10:08:47 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:12}] to 127.0.0.1:27017
Oct 18, 2016 10:08:47 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 2, 10]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=4, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=1546838}
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in com.storeApp.config.SpringMongoConfig1: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/ClassTypeInformation;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at com.storeApp.core.StoreMainApp.main(StoreMainApp.java:20)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/ClassTypeInformation;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/ClassTypeInformation;
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper.<clinit>(DefaultMongoTypeMapper.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.<init>(MappingMongoConverter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getDefaultMongoConverter(MongoTemplate.java:2039)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:217)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:202)
    at com.storeApp.config.SpringMongoConfig1.mongoTemplate(SpringMongoConfig1.java:25)
    at com.storeApp.config.SpringMongoConfig1$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$81e5bc96.CGLIB$mongoTemplate$0(<generated>)
    at com.storeApp.config.SpringMongoConfig1$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$81e5bc96$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$52d3ef2d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at com.storeApp.config.SpringMongoConfig1$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$81e5bc96.mongoTemplate(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 14 more

Not getting where is the problem...
```

Comment: You've probably got a version conflict between the dependency being pulled in by Spring Boot and the direct Spring Data dependency. Try grabbing the latest release version of each of them.

Comment: already done that....no luck

Comment: Actually, you probably don't need the spring-data-mongodb dependency at all, since Spring Boot should pull that in. Try removing that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You only need below dependency and it will bring you all needed jars.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

The error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` you are getting is for `ClassTypeInformation` class. Please check whether **spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar** is present after you build your project. If not, then try cleaning up your build environment and update maven project.

Answer (score 4):

A little late to the party, but here is what you need.

If you are trying to use a custom data manipulation rather than using the default inbuilt `mongo repositories`, then you need a `mongoTemplate` (kind of jdbc template but lets you define your own implementation of the client, i.e, the `mongo client` , in this case) and optionally `mongoOperations` on top of it(`Mongo Operations` is kind of a wrapper on top of the `mongoTemplate`)

You need the following dependencies - pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

MongoConfig.java

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")

public class MongoConfig{

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
    private String mongoHost;
    
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
    private String mongopPort;
        
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String mongoDB;

    /*Client vs FactoryClient
     * 
     * Factory bean that creates the com.mongodb.MongoClient instance
     * 
     * Classes attributed with @Repostiory may throw mongo related exceptions. Declaring an instance of MonogClientFactoryBean
     * helps in translating them to spring data exceptions which can then be caught using @ExceptionHandling
     * */
     public @Bean MongoClientFactoryBean mongo() throws Exception {
          MongoClientFactoryBean mongo = new MongoClientFactoryBean();
          mongo.setHost("localhost");
          MongoClientOptions clientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder().applicationName("FeddBackAPI_DB")
                      .connectionsPerHost(2000)
                      .connectTimeout(4000)
                      //.maxConnectionIdleTime(1000000000)
                      .maxWaitTime(3000)
                      .retryWrites(true)
                      .socketTimeout(4000)
                      .sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(true)//this is very risky
                      
                      .build();
          mongo.setMongoClientOptions(clientOptions);
          
          return mongo;
     }
}
```

DataSourceConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@Import(value=MongoClientFactory.class)
public class DataSourceConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    Mongo mongo;
    
    @Autowired
    Environment env;
    
    @Bean
    public String test() {
        System.out.println("mongo"+mongo);
        return "rer";
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("customMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        
        //MongoClient is the actual pool used by mongo. Create it using client factory then, autoclosing of threads are handled on its own
        MongoDbFactory factory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory((MongoClient) mongo, "mongo_test");
        MongoTemplate template = new MongoTemplate(factory);
        
        return template;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Qualifier(value="customMongoOps")
    public MongoOperations mongoOps() {
        MongoOperations ops = mongoTemplate();
        return ops;
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory factory() {
        MongoDbFactory factory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory((MongoClient) mongo, "mongo_test");
        return factory;
    }
    
//  @Bean
//  public GridFsTemplate gridFsTemplate() {
//      return new GridFsTemplate(mongo, converter)
//  }
    
    
}
```

This should successfully create the `mongoTemplate` and `mongoOperations` and you should be able to make use of them in your DAO or service and access them.

PersonService.java

```
    @Service
    public class PersonService {
        @Autowired
        private PersonRepository personRepo;
        
        @Autowired
        PersonSequenceServiceImpl seqService;
        
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier(value="customMongoOps")
        MongoOperations mongoOps;
        
        public List<Person> findAllPersons() {
            return personRepo.findAll();
        }
        
        public List<Person> createAndFindAllPersons() {
            Person p1 = new Person( "another1", "ll1", 30);
            Person p2 = new Person( "another2", "ll2", 30);
            
            if(!mongoOps.collectionExists(Person.class)) {
                mongoOps.dropCollection("Person_table");
            }
            //return personRepo.save(person);
            
                    
            System.out.println("P1 data before inserting:"+p1);
            mongoOps.insert(Arrays.asList(p1,p2), Person.class);
            //mongoOps.dropCollection(Person.class);
            return mongoOps.findAll(Person.class);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Please go through the MongoAutoConfiguration class file once to get an idea of what beans are required

Comment: Thanks dude, you saved me!!

Comment: :) great to know it helped

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not a technically justified solution. But after trying several alternatives, I just **closed Eclipse** and **deleted all the .m2 folder content**. 
Then, I retried to import the Project ina  new Workspace and compiled. 
Surprise! This time it worked :)
Sometimes rebooting works ;)